# Why do I get this Invalid decimal literal error when trying to use TRL to fine tune a model?

Tags: python, deep-learning, syntax, nlp, huggingface-transformers

I am new to LLM and learning how to fine tune a LLM model.
I was reading an article on Medium and trying to run the following code in the article in colab.

```
#install trl
!pip install trl
# clone the repo for the script
git clone https://github.com/lvwerra/trl

# start training !
python trl/examples/scripts/sft_trainer.py \
  --model_name meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-hf \
  --dataset_name timdettmers/openassistant-guanaco \
  --use_peft \
  --batch_size 4 \
  --gradient_accumulation_steps 2
```

```
  File "<ipython-input-11-c07a8b5c25f5>", line 8
    --model_name meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-hf \
                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid decimal literal
```

I am not a python expert. So, I want to know why there is such an error and how to fix it?

Thank you very much in advanced!

I googled this error. But I was unable to fix it.

Comment: This seems like a Jupyter Notebook issue, it's treating your input as an expression, not a string.

Answer (score 0):

Just add an `!` before calling python in the notebook cell by the following:

```
# start training !
!python trl/examples/scripts/sft_trainer.py \
  --model_name meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-hf \
  --dataset_name timdettmers/openassistant-guanaco \
  --use_peft \
  --batch_size 4 \
  --gradient_accumulation_steps 2
```

**NOTE:** You should apparently replace `git` with `!git`. Also, in this [repo](https://github.com/huggingface/trl), there is no `sft_trained.py` script, I guess you are referring to `sft.py` which seems to take the same input arguments.